# Interlacing with arithmetic progressions?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, integers, arithmetic-progressions

1. Given integers $0<a_1<\dots<a_t$ and $0<b_1<\dots<b_t$ with $a_t<b_t<M$ can we find integers $m,n,m',n'\in\mathbb Z$ such that

$$ma_i+n<m'b_i+n'<ma_{i+1}+n$$ holds at every $i\in\{1,\dots,t-1\}$?

2. If so is there a fixed $c>0$ such that $\max(|m|,|n|,|m'|,|n'|)<t^{\log^c M}$ holds?

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334885/interlacing-sequences-by-polynomials.

Comment: Why negative vote here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no to your first question, i.e., is there always $m,n,m',n'\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ma_i+n<m'b_i+n'<ma_{i+1}+n \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

is true for all $1 \le i \le t - 1$. First, note that, from \eqref{eq1}, requiring $ma_i + n \lt ma_{i+1} + n$, where $a_i \lt a_{i+1}$, means $m \gt 0$. Thus, since the values of $m'b_i + n'$ need to be increasing with increasing values of $i$, with $b_i \lt b_{i+1}$, means that $m' \gt 0$.

Consider $t = 5$, so the set of inequalities become

$$a_1 m + n \lt b_1 m' + n' \lt a_2 m + n \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$a_2 m + n \lt b_2 m' + n' \lt a_3 m + n \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
$$a_3 m + n \lt b_3 m' + n' \lt a_4 m + n \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
$$a_4 m + n \lt b_4 m' + n' \lt a_5 m + n \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Combining \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} gives

$$a_1 m + n \lt b_1 m' + n' \lt b_2 m' + n' \lt a_3 m + n \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

This means the difference between the $2$ middle parts is less than the difference of the $2$ outer parts, i.e.,

$$(b_2 m' + n') - (b_1 m' + n') \lt (a_3 m + n) - (a_1 m + n) \; \iff \; (b_2 - b_1)m' \lt (a_3 - a_1)m \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Next, comparing \eqref{eq2} with \eqref{eq5}, you have

$$b_1 m' + n' \lt a_2 m + n \lt a_4 m + n \lt b_4 m' + n' \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

Once again, the difference between the $2$ middle parts is less than the difference of the $2$ outer parts, i.e.,

$$(a_4 m + n) - (a_2 m + n) \lt (b_4 m' + n') - (b_1 m' + n') \; \iff \; (a_4 - a_2)m \lt (b_4 - b_1)m' \tag{9}\label{eq9}$$

Now, if $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $a_3 = 3$, $a_4 = 6$, $a_5 = 7$, and $b_1 = 4$, $b_2 = 6$, $b_3 = 7$, $b_4 = 8$, $b_5 = 9$. In this case, \eqref{eq7} becomes

$$(6 - 4)m' \lt (3 - 1)m \; \iff \; m' \lt m \tag{10}\label{eq10}$$

and \eqref{eq9} becomes

$$(6 - 2)m \lt (8 - 4)m' \; \iff \; m \lt m' \tag{11}\label{eq11}$$

However, this contradicts \eqref{eq10}, so in this case there are no such $m,n,m',n'\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note, also, that not only is $a_5 \lt b_5$ as required, but also $a_i \lt b_i$ for all $1 \le i \le 5$.

Nonetheless, there are cases where it does work. As for those cases always satisfying your second question, consider $t = 3$, with $a_i = i$, $b_i = 2i$ for $1 \le i \le 3$, with $a_i \lt b_i$ once again. The equations are now

$$m + n \lt 2m' + n' \lt 2m + n \tag{12}\label{eq12}$$
$$2m + n \lt 4m' + n' \lt 3m + n \tag{13}\label{eq13}$$

In this case, have $m = 2k$ and $m' = k$ for any integer $k \gt 0$, and $n = n' - 1$ for any $n' \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then you can confirm both \eqref{eq12} and \eqref{eq13} are satisfied since they become $2k + n' - 1 \lt 2k + n' \lt 4k + n' - 1$ and $4k + n' - 1 \lt 4k + n' \lt 6k + n' - 1$. Also, although $\max(|m|,|n|,|m'|,|n'|)$ exists for any given $m'$ and $n'$, as these values are unbounded, there's no upper limit for this maximum and, thus, there's for any given $t, M \gt 0$, there's no fixed $c \gt 0$ such that $\max(|m|,|n|,|m'|,|n'|)<t^{\log^c M}$ holds.

Comment: Do you know this as well? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334885/interlacing-sequences-by-polynomials

Comment: @Turbo I took a look at that linked post earlier since you included it in your question. If I understand what it states correctly, there are always a set of polynomials which work for any given set of values. However, you've asked here about only linear polynomials, with my answer showing that's not always true. I haven't considered the more general case to any extent, but intuitively it makes sense to me. As for the rest of that question, I don't really have any suggestions as to how to handle it. I hope somebody else on MathOverflow can help you to solve it.

Comment: What would be $\max(|m|,|n|,|m'|,|n'|)$ if $2\leq t\leq4$?

Comment: @Turbo I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If it's in regards to my last paragraph, then $\max(|m|,|n|,|m'|,|n'|)$ depends on what values of $m'$ and $n'$ you pick. I realize I worded that part poorly as each possibility does have a maximum, so I shouldn't have said it didn't. However, I have now made it clear that I was referring to it not have any upper bound instead. If you were asking about something else, please let me know.

Comment: I just wonder if $t<5$ we have what we need and only at $t\geq5$ we fail.

Comment: @Turbo For your question #$1$, i.e., always finding integers $m,n,m',n'\in\mathbb Z$, I believe you're correct. I did a few checks, and I assume you did as well, but I couldn't find any way to determine it will ever fail for $t \lt 5$.